# Create a movie from an array of images

Tags: image, movie

I have the following code snippet:

```
X=[]
for val in range(64):
   ap_pix=amp_phas[:,val]
   im=plt.imshow(ap_pix.reshape(50,50),cmap=plt.get_cmap('plasma'))
   X.append(im)
```

amp_phas is a (2500 x 64) array so that each step of the loop creates a 50 x 50 image that is stored into the array X. 
I am using Python 3 in Jupyter notebook.

How can I create a movie or a slide show from the array X?

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Which programming language are you using? What is the exact output you need? Creating **a movie** does not describe your desired output clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using imageio and mimsave.

Here is my final code:

```
filenames=[]      # array that stores the filename of each image
 for val in range(64):
  ap_pix=amp_phas[:,val]    # array that contains the image data
  im=plt.imshow(ap_pix.reshape(50,50),cmap=plt.get_cmap('plasma'))
  plt.colorbar()
  a='C:/yada/yada/'+ str(val)+'.png'     #filename of each array with the location where it is to be saved
filenames.append(a)    # adding the file name to filenames[] 
plt.savefig(a)      #saving the figure
plt.clf()         #clearing the figure so that the colorbars don't pile up

import imageio
images = []        #array to store the images
for filename in filenames:
  images.append(imageio.imread(filename))  #reading the images into into images[]
imageio.mimsave('C:/yada/yada/movie.gif', images)  #movie making
```

The frame rate of the gif can be adjusted in the following way:

```
  imageio.mimsave('C:/yada/yada/movie.gif', images,duration=0.5)
```